# EC2 Ubuntu Lucid Hostname/ServerName

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, hostname, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to move my server from linode to EC2 and am following the guide located here - http://library.linode.com/getting-started/

One problem I have is when I set my hostname to my public DNS:

```
echo "ec2-46-51-***-**" > /etc/hostname
```

And add to my elastic ip and public DNS to /etc/hosts:

```
46.51.***.*** c2-46-51-131-72.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com c2-46-51-131-72
```

I can no longer log on. Should I be using internal IP and private dns names?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal and private IPs/DNs are only for use from within the Amazon network (i.e., from other EC2 servers).  The elastic IP only allows you to bind a *static* IP to a chosen VM.  You should probably be doing one of two things:

1. Connect to the public IP that's generated whenever you launch a new instance, or
2. Bind the elastic IP and use that.

Neither should require you modifying the network setup on the VM.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. So for a web server I don't need to change my hosts file at all? Or change my hostname?

Comment: You shouldn't, no, but try it without touching the system files first to confirm.  When tweaking configs, you should always start with the defaults, and then work from there.